# Лопая или как?

Tags: словообразование

Пузырь жвачки лопается. А если мы его, то как? Лопаем? А если мы делаем что-то, то "лопая"? В общем, какое подобрать деепричастие?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Он сломал игрушку – игрушка сломалась,  он кормит ребенка – ребенок ест,  он положил книгу – книга лежит.

Эти ситуации связаны каузативными (причинными)  отношениями.  Для непереходных  глаголов «лопнуть, лопаться" такой лексической пары  «заставить лопнуть  (перех.) – лопнуть (неперех.)»  нет.

Соответственно, образовать деепричастие, отнесенное к производителю действия,  невозможно.

Comment: Да, согласен с вами. Это т.н. лексически неполные глаголы.

Answer (score 0):

Да, Вы совершенно правы. Мы лопаем пузыри от жвачки. Они - лопают, а кто-то смеется, лопая пузыри от жвачки.

Comment: Кто они - пузыри? Тогда - лопаются.

Answer (score 0):

А, может быть, ограничиться традиционным "надувая"? Результат-то обычно тот же. :)